# Reversing a Floored Xorshift128+

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

We suppose that we have N consecutive numbers generated by JavaScript using: `math.floor(math.random()*multiple)`, knowing that `math.random()` generates consecutive xorshift128+ values.

I found that there exist a script capable of reversing this using Z3 (https://github.com/d0nutptr/v8_rand_buster) and it works perfectly as long as the multiple is superior to 1000. It models the floor by comparing the mantissa generated by the solver with the mantissa of the target numbers + 1.

Unfortunately when the multiple is in the range of 100 and less, the script doesn't work at all, and is stuck indefinitely when N is larger than 16. I suppose it happens because too much precision is lost when we floor after a low multiple.

My questions are :

1. Does Z3 really breaks because of the loss in precision or is it because of something else.
2. Is it theoretically possible to recover a 128 internal state of a xorshift using numbers less than 100. How much would be needed using what strategy.
3. Supposing that its JavaScript of Chromium V8, and that the seed is only 64 bit (second 64 bit half being a simple Murmurhash3 of the first half, and the first half itself is a Murmurhash3 of a 64b it timer seed), would that help?

Comment: what exactly is a floored XORShift128+? A definition, not a link to some code please